# Jquery running through loop with timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

I want to give an item with the **id** from the json array give the class active. But after the **seconds** from the array, it should give the next item the class active. And so go on with the loop.

**Index.html**

```
<div id="5"></div>
<div id="8"></div>
<div id="11"></div>
```

**Scheme.json:**

```
[
    {
        "id":"5",
        "seconds":"3"
    },
    {
        "id":"8",
        "seconds":"2"
    },
    {
        "id":"11",
        "seconds":"4"
    }
]
```

**Script.js:**

```
function loop() {
    $.getJSON("assets/scheme.json", function(data) {
        //
    });
}
```

Comment: please add more code what you did.

Comment: You know about `setTimeout`... You have the `duration` to be passed.. Where did you stuck ?

Comment: I know setTimeout. But I have the loop through the array first, and then it requests all the timeouts the same time.

Comment: Have your loop inside the AJAX result, not the other way round. Some form of recursion may be easiest. Depending on length of the array that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would do it - use `setTimeout` to selectively add the class, and call the next item once done

```js
var data = [
    {
        "id":"5",
        "seconds":"3"
    },
    {
        "id":"8",
        "seconds":"2"
    },
    {
        "id":"11",
        "seconds":"4"
    }
];

// put everything below here inside your callback from getJSON
function setActive(data, index){
  let item = data[index];
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('#' + item.id).addClass("active");
   if(index<data.length-1)
          setActive(data,index+1);
  }, item.seconds*1000)
}

// start execution at the first item
setActive(data,0);
```

```css
.active{ background-color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="5">Five</div>
<div id="8">Eight</div>
<div id="11">Eleven</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to accumulate the seconds between items

```
function loop() {
    $.getJSON("assets/scheme.json", function(data) {
        var seconds = 0;
        for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            seconds += data[i].seconds * 1000;
            setTimeout(function(){ setActive(data[i].id)}, seconds );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can either use ES6 let, or an IIFE to control the variable scope.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//take off class active
function unactive(){
  
  $(".active").removeClass("active");

}

//add class active and continue recursive loop
function activate(current,data){
  
  unactive();//unactive all before
  $('#'+data[current].id).addClass("active");
  
  current++;
  
  if (current<data.length){
     setTimeout(activate.bind(this,current,data),parseInt(data[current].seconds)*1000);//run again
    
    }else{
      //here is end but we can start again from 0
      setTimeout(startActive.bind(this,data),parseInt(data[current-1].seconds)*1000)
      
    }
  
};

//starts our loop
function startActive(data){
  
  var current=0;
  setTimeout(activate.bind(this,current,data),parseInt(data[current].seconds)*1000);
  
};

//data from json
var fromJson=[
    {
        "id":"5",
        "seconds":"3"
    },
    {
        "id":"8",
        "seconds":"2"
    },
    {
        "id":"11",
        "seconds":"4"
    }
];

//run
startActive(fromJson);
```

```css
.active{

  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="5">5</div>
<div id="8">8</div>
<div id="11">11</div>
```

Above code gets data from object collection ( in Your code collection will be from ajax ) and do recursive loop. I also repeat loop after last element, and everything goes from begging, if such repeat is unwanted just remove **else** from **activate** function.